# Developers can't see projects in Team Explorer/TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

For some reason our developers can only add projects that they've created to Team Explorer, even though they've all been given rights to the other projects. I created a top level group and added all of their AD users to it, and I assigned that group rights to access all of our projects.

They can see the projects in Source Control Explorer, and are able to do their work, but if they try to add a project to Team Explorer, the Connect to Team Project dialog box only shows their own projects.

Is there some other set of permissions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make everyone can see and operate each others project, you need to put your team group into `Project Collection Administrators` in Collection level

If you don't want everyone have admin right,

you need to tell everyone to put the team group into `Readers` group in the team project they created.

Actually, I don't think there is a way to create a group in Collection level to access all team projects.

In fact, I think the best solution for you situation should be everyone use the same Team project and put everyone in the Reader group in that team project.

So everyone can create their own project under that team project instead of creating their own team project.

If you still want to let everyone create their own team project,
I suggest you use [Team Foundation Server Administration Tool](http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/) to manage group membership.

Comment: Cool, the TFS Administration Tool scratched the itch. Thanks.

Comment: For those who dont have TFS 2012 here is the 2010 version of the Admin Tool http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/releases/view/57795

Answer (score 0):

Permission right usually given on team project level basic. By "top level group" if you mean by giving permission at collection level. then i will suggest you try adding member at 'team project level' under any required group with necessary permission. if you cant add the member ask the admin of the team project to add separately.

you can directly access the security page through web access by.

[TFS web access url]/[Collection]/[team project]/_admin/_security

Answer (score -1):

Under the "TeamExplorer - Connect" there is an option to "Select Team Projects..." When you click on this a box should pop-up titled "Connect to Team Foundation Server" that has a select dropbox, a "Team Project Collections" panel and a "Team Projects" panel. The latter has a list of projects in the collection and each has a checkbox next to them.
Make sure the projects you are interested in are in the list, and have the box checked. You can use the "Select All" checkbox to turn them all on at once.
HTH